VScode: Kill Server on Host with password authentication
I am using VScode to connect to develop code on a remote server (my host). Since its usage is shared among several users (of which I seem to be the only one using VScode), I would like to shutdown all the VScode-server processes on the host.
The host is setup such that Kerberos takes care of the authentication. Due to the implementation we have, to avoid Kerberos-tickets issues I cannot connect to the host using an ssh-key, I must use password authentication.
When I run the Remote-SSH: Kill VS Code Server on Host command on VScode to shutdown the server processes, the window closes but the processes on the host keep on running. I have noticed that a password prompt pops-up right before the window closes, but I do not have the time to type it in. Moreover, after the window closes, I am not able to reconnect to the host for a few minutes telling that port 22 is unavailable on the host (I guess there is something about the former request still holding and I must wait until it timeouts).
I have not found answers to any similar questions on the internet, can somebody hint me if there is a way to solve this issue?
